# Google Place Reviews API - Photos return 403 on pageload

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm currently using the Google Places API to pull reviews onto a webpage. Everything is working fine except for the Photos of the people leaving reviews. When trying to get the photo of the reviewer, it's returning a 403 Forbidden on every other page load. It seems that there might be a rate limit perhaps?

The problem is I can't find any documentation about rate limits and how to get the picture to display without issue. Am I missing something in the docs?

My API call is this;

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PLACE_ID&key=API_KEY
```

That returns quite a long JSON array (I've cut it down). One of those fields is;

```
{
   "result" : {
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "profile_photo_url" : "//lh5.googleusercontent.com/url/photo.jpg"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Like I said, if I refresh a couple of times it'll cause a 403 error for the images get request. Anyway to cache or allow more requests?

Comment: Anything in your javascript console? Would you maybe create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage

Comment: The only thing in the console was the GET request saying it returned a 403 Forbidden when fetching the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this was happening. It's to do with rate limits on the photo media which is why it was giving a 403 error in the console. The [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage) outline the limits for the media requested.

*An excerpt of the docs...*

> The Google Places API Web Service enforces **a default limit of 1,000
>   free requests per 24 hour period**, calculated as the sum of client-side
>   and server-side requests. If your app exceeds the initial limit, the
>   app will start failing. You can increase this limit free of charge, up
>   to 150,000 requests per 24 hour period, by enabling billing on the
>   Google API Console to verify your identity. A credit card is required
>   for verification. We ask for your credit card purely to validate your
>   identity. Your card will not be charged for use of the Google Places
>   API Web Service.

Best thing to do is to cache the media once it's requested to avoid going over the limit which is especially useful if you're reloading the page lots of times for testing local development changes.